# difference beetween decimate an array and decimate function

Tags: python, power-spectral-density, decimation

i'am actually comparing data and i got a question that i cannot anwser,

here is what i understand.

nanometrique move

X[::256] : decimate and take 1/256 point in the vector (blue)

decimate(X, 256, ftype='fir') : decimate and apply a LP filter (orange)

questions are : why those peaks on decimate methode ? and as i know of my lessons a LP filter does not permit a 30dB gap beetween those figure, an idea why ?

for the PSD i apply mlab.psd function

[image: what i get]

any sugestions ?

up after comment :
thanks for your reply

i'll try to explain clearly,
blue signal is raw data with decimation of 256 without any filter

orange signal is apply with the function decimate on the same raw data and that function decimate apply a FIR

for the LP i don't even know is frequencial response du to the function

the original signal is like 200 000 000 data and it is too heavy for my computer ...i reduce the raw decimation : 256 to 29

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the two different approaches between blue and orange as your question is not very clear. Aren't you saying you apply a low pass filter to the signal in blue which becomes the signal in orange? Can you also plot the frequency response of your low pass filter and what the PSD of the original signal looks like without any decimation?

Comment: post as been updated

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. If the original data is too big, then operate on a smaller piece where you can show everything. Show the input waveform and its spectrum, then show the decimated waveform and its spectrum, and then show the same after low pass filtering- and then with that show what your question actually is. Your decimation would likely be the combination of low pass filtering followed by down sampling, so the peaks at the start and end of the time domain plot shown are an artifact of that filtering since down sampling would not effect that.

Comment: thanks one more for your reply
your reply on my question about artifact and i know were i should go thanks one more !